# C# Array / List performance difference

Tags: c#, performance

Consider the following methods:

```
static Stopwatch ArrayTest(int size)
{
    var arr = new int[size];
    Stopwatch stw = new Stopwatch();
    stw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = i / div;
    }
    var rnd = new Random(1);
    var sz2 = size / div;
    for (int i = 0; i < sz2; i++)
    {
        var sz = size - i;
        var ix = rnd.Next(sz);
        Array.Copy(arr, ix + 1, arr, ix, size - ix - 1);
        arr[sz - 1] = 0;
    }
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size - sz2; i++)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    stw.Stop();
    Console.Write("     Array: {0}", sum);
    return stw;
}

static Stopwatch ListTest(int size)
{
    var lst = new List<int>();
    Stopwatch stw = new Stopwatch();
    stw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        lst.Add(i / div);
    }
    var rnd = new Random(1);
    var sz2 = size / div;
    for (int i = 0; i < sz2; i++)
    {
        var ix = rnd.Next(lst.Count);
        lst.RemoveAt(ix);
    }
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
    {
        sum += lst[i];
    }
    stw.Stop();
    Console.Write("      List: {0}", sum);
    return stw;
}
```

div = 2 and size = 200000.
Running this (complied at Release) produces the following:

```
 Array: 5012641699  12.8367529 s
  List: 5012641699   6.1027289 s
```

According to http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib List.RemoveAt is implemented like this:

```
    // Removes the element at the given index. The size of the list is
    // decreased by one.
    // 
    public void RemoveAt(int index) {
        if ((uint)index >= (uint)_size) {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
        Contract.EndContractBlock();
        _size--;
        if (index < _size) {
            Array.Copy(_items, index + 1, _items, index, _size - index);
        }
        _items[_size] = default(T);
        _version++;
    }
```

So I wonder why the ArrayTest requires twice the time that ListTest does.  It seems to me that they are both doing pretty much the same thing, in fact I'd expect ArrayTest to be faster due to less  overhead.  Perhaps I have missed something obvious?

**Update**
Let me explain the example.  The idea was to measure the performance under conditions of random deletes (while still retaining indexed access).  The first part of each method initializes an array/list where each element in the array is 1/2 the index (integer division).  The next part randomly removes 1/2 the elements.  The last loop simply sums the values remaining in the array/list which is used as a checksum (to compare results).  Profiling the code shows that in ArrayTest the Array.Copy uses the most time and in ListTest the lst.RemoveAt uses the most time.

I will attempt to replicate the behavior in a simpler example and update it here.

Comment: In the `Array.Copy` line of `ArrayTest`, should it really read `size - ix - 1`? `size` does not change, aren't you copying too many elements?

Comment: Have you considered making a simple piece of code? It's a bit hard to follow your logic there to ensure it's doing the same. In particular I would like to verify that you're in fact copying the right number of elements. I made a simpler test removing the 0th element of an array and list, and for 200K elements, the results are within 0.1% of each other when averaged over a number of runs. I don't think you're measuring what you think you're measuring.

Comment: This means that the benchmark is broken. This is the standard case on Stack Overflow. I will not invest the time to look into it today. Find the error in your benchmark.

Comment: I would narrow stopwatch start and stop to see if it is difference in removing or maybe in insertion.

Comment: @odyss-jii.  Yes the size - ix - 1 is correct.  It looks a bit different from the RemoveAt code because they decrement size before the Array.Copy.

Comment: @Dweeberly, yeah but you don't decrement `size` for the next iteration of the loop. I'm not thinking about the `-1`, I'm referring to the subsequent calls/iterations. Each time `RemoveAt` is called `size` will be smaller than the previous time, in your code it will always be the same. Shouldn't it be `sz - ix -1`?

Comment: @odyss-jii You are correct!  That is exactly the issue.  If you want to make that an answer I'll be glad to mark it.  Thank you.

Comment: As I said: The benchmark is invalid. Here's some guidance: If the benchmark is surprising, it is probably invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the line:

```
Array.Copy(arr, ix + 1, arr, ix, size - ix - 1);
```

in method `ArrayTest`. It should read

```
Array.Copy(arr, ix + 1, arr, ix, sz - ix - 1);
```

since the variable `size` is not changed when the array is resized, instead `sz`, the actual size, is calculated in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

There is a flaw in your test program. You've made it overly convoluted and thus hard to prove on paper. The only way to figure out what your code is doing is by debugging, hand-calculating everything.

So instead I made a simpler test.

```
void Main()
{
    const int LENGTH = 200000;

    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var a = new int[LENGTH];
    for (int index = LENGTH-1; index > 0; index--)
        Array.Copy(a, 1, a, 0, index);
    sw.Stop();
    sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump();

    var l = new List<int>(a);

    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int index = LENGTH-1; index > 0; index--)
        l.RemoveAt(0);
    sw.Stop();
    sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump();
}
```

It simply "removes" the 0th element of an array, and a list. The results on my machine are:

```
3366
3442

3270
3242

3343
3385
```

That's 3 runs.